# Introduction to viscosity solutions theory

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation, viscosity-solutions

Can you recommend an introduction to *viscosity solutions theory*? More specifically, I'm looking for a modern treatment similar to Chapter 10 of Evans's *Partial Differential Equations*, but somewhat more detailed and comprehensive.

(Of course, I'm aware of the *[User's Guide](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9207212)*, but it is not quite what I'm looking for).

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend the book by Bardi and Capuzzo-Dolcetta.

"Optimal Control and Viscosity Solutions of Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman Equations" Bardi, Martino, Capuzzo-Dolcetta, Italo

For something shorter and more introductory you can check out my notes:

http://math.umn.edu/~jwcalder/222BS16/viscosity_solutions.pdf